# Declaring an associative array inside a php class

Tags: php, class, properties, declaration, associative-array

I have a problem with declaring a *property* that is an **associative array** inside a **php** class.

```
class Friends {

private $db;
public $friendRequest;
public $addedUser;
public $frName;

function __construct(){     
    $this->friendRequest = array();     
    $this->addedUser = array();
    $this->frName = array();
}  
public function friendInfo($getId) {
    $this->db = new DataBase(); 
    $this->friendRequest = $this->db->frFrom($getId);

    foreach ($this->friendRequest['userId'] as $key => $friendId) {

        $this->addedUser = $this->db->frFrom($friendId);

        $this->frName['name'] = $this->addedUser[0]['nickName'] ; 
        $this->frName['id'] = $this->friendRequest['id'][$key] ;
        $this->frName['friendId'] = $this->friendRequest['userId'][$key];

    }   
    return $this->frName;
 }

}
```

I am getting an error that says **userId** variable is *undefined*. I have tried to define the assoitive array by adding another constructor such as

```
function __construct($this->friendRequest){     
    $this->friendRequest['userId'] = array();        
}
```

I am still getting an error for not defining the **userId** variable. 
I also have to declare the other associative arrays but if I figure out the **friendRequest['user_id']** array problem I should be able to fix the other ones.
Can somebody help me out on this?

I had originally written this code without declaring the variables while I was working on it on my *web server*. I was *not getting any errors* and It was working *perfectly fine*.

But when I decided it to bring my application into my *local machine* that runs **XAMPP** server, I started to see the errors. Therefore I realized that I have to decalere the *properties* just like how I have declared the:

```
private $db;
```

and then by using **$this->** calling the properties, which in this case they are associative arrays.

the original code is as here and *it didn't give me any error* when i was ruuning on webserver.

```
class Friends {

private $db;

public function friendInfo($getId) {
    $this->db = new DataBase();
    $friendRequest = array();   
    $friendRequest = $this->db->frFrom($getId);

    foreach ($friendRequest['userId'] as $key => $friendId) {

        $addedUser = $this->db->frFrom($friendId);

        $frName['name'] = $addedUser[0]['nickName'] ; 
        $frName['id'] = $friendRequest['id'][$key] ;
        $frName['friendId'] = $friendRequest['userId'][$key];

    }

    return $frName;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->friendRequest` appears to be coming out of a database. if you `dump_var($this->friendRequest)` you'll be able to see what that value is.